# How can I read data as string[] by csvhelper

Tags: csvhelper

Is there a way to read CSV data in a form of string[] using CsvHelper? I want something like

```
csvReader reader = new Reader(dataFilePath);
string[] csvLine = reader.ReadLine();
```

or

```
List<string[]> allLines = reader.ReadAllLines();
```

E.g. if the file looks like this:

```
Id,Name
1,one
```

I need the result to look like this:

```
List<string[]> allLines = new List<string[]>()
{ {"Id", "Name"}, {"1", "one"} };
```

The GetRecords method parses the data which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** for current `CsvHelper`, Version 30.0.1

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var allLines = new List<string[]>();

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            allLines.Add(csv.Context.Reader.Parser.Record );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have changed now. You can access the data in a string array in ```csv.Context.Reader.Parser.Record```